# Linear independence of trig functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello there I am having a bit of confusion in regard to solving if the functions $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent or not, the answer given is independent but no solution.

$$f(x)=\cos(3x) $$ and

$$g(x)=5\cos^{3}x-10\cos(x)$$

I tried to do this calculating the wronskian using that $$f'(x)=-3\sin(3x)$$ 
and $$g'(x)=-15\cos^{2}x\sin x+10\sin x$$

but I just can't seem to see how it is always non zero. There seems to be roots .Can someone help? Thanks a lot

Comment: Your $g'(x)$ should be $g'(x) = -15\cos^{2}(x)\sin(x) + 10\sin(x)$

Comment: Thanks yea that is what I have had , but same problem . Il edit

Comment: do you know the difinition of linear independence?

Comment: Yes sir I beleive so , I thought it means that the only solution to the homogeneous equation of any linear combination of these functions would have to imply both Scalars c and d must be zero

Comment: $\cos(3x)=4\cos(x)^3-3\cos(x)$

Comment: Should I try the wronskian with that?

Comment: Because I have tried and it still did not work , could you verify that if you do it all works out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $$a(4\cos(x)^3-3\cos(x))+b(5\cos(x)^3-10\cos(x))=0$$
is equivalent to
$$\cos(x)^3(4a+5b)+\cos(x)(-3a-10b)=0$$
for all real $x$
from here we get $a=b=0$

Comment: Ah I see so il solve the system of equations . Thanks

Comment: thanks I got it , but how does this explain the wronskian seemingly being able to be zero , do you know where the mistake could be?

Comment: Sonnhard, Thanks again. I am still confused about the wronskian aspect. if you have time and don't mind maybe you could take a look at it? it is my most recent question on my profile with title involving the wronskian