# Trouble with Wronskian

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I am having some trouble justifying to myself something. Please see my other question in which I talked about solving  if the functions f and g are linearly independent or not where

$$f(x)=\cos(3x)$$

and

$$g(x)=5\cos^3 x−10\cos(x)$$

So , I was able to do this following the hint provided in
[Linear independence of trig functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281944/linear-independence-of-trig-functions/1281976#1281976)
 and I solved that it was linearly independent, and that was apparently the correct answer.

Here is my issue, when I try to do the same problem using the Wronskian,
(noting)
$$f′(x)=−3\sin (3x)$$
and
$$g′(x)=−15\cos^2 x\sin x+10\sin x$$

but I just can't seem to see how it is always non zero. There seems to be roots

For some reason, I keep getting the Wronskian as $W=-50\sin x \cos^3 x$ which indeed does have real roots. So this is confusing my because I was under the impression that if the Wronskian was ever zero than this would imply via Abels theorem that it was zero everywhere as well in that interval.

So is it that I must only evaluate exactly zero when dealing with functions in regard to the Wronskian? Doe plugging in x into the final answer or form on wronskian not tell us anything ?

Thank you all

Comment: Why $-15cos^2(x)sin(x)+10sin(x)$? To my understanding, i have that $g'(x)=-15sen(3x)+10sin(x)$

Comment: Oops it should be cubed in the formatting , thanks

Comment: Because you are treating with functions, and $-50sin(x)cos^3(x)$ is not the zero function, you can say that W is not zero.

Comment: But is not important that the function can be evaluated as zero for some x

Comment: I think that you confusion came because the abbuse of notation between the zero scalar and the zero function. Just remember what kind of objects are you dealing with and you will have no problems.

Comment: Nope. That is not important. The important thing is that the function for all values is not the function zero.

Comment: Also note that the wronskian takes functions and returns functions, not scalars.

Answer (score 1):

here is what i know about the wronskians. suppose $f, g$ are solutions of a linear differential equation $$Ly = y'' + by' + cy = 0$$ and $w = fg' - f'g.$  then $w$ satisfies the ables equation $$w' = aw$$

from these you can conclude that if the wronskian of $f$ and $g$ are either identically zero or is never zero.

this does not mean the wronskian, which is defined for any two smooth functions, has the same property as two solutions of the second order linear differential equation $Ly = 0.$ what this implies is that $$f(x) = \cos 3x, g(x) = 5 \cos^3 x - 10 \cos x$$ cannot be the solutions of $$y'' + by' + cy = 0$$ for any $b, c.$

Comment: It should be $w'=-bw$, and you need to qualify that $b,c$ are continuous functions, at singularities the Wronskian can take the value zero (in the limit approaching the singularity).